# How do I discover and control what channel my WiFi adaptor is running on?

Tags: wifi

I'm using an Edimax EW-7811Un 802.11b/g/n WiFi adaptor on my RPi model B.  It works well.

I am doing some coexistence testing that requires me to run the WiFi in the 802.11b/g 2.4GHz band rather than in the 802.11n 5Ghz band.

1. How do I discover what channel the Edimax is running on?
2. How can I force it to run in 11b/g mode (2.4GHz) rather than 11n (5GHz)?

Note: I don't have admin access to my WiFi router, so queries and configuration must be performed on the RPi, not the router.

Update: For reference, here's the results of `lsusb`:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0403:8a28 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd Rainforest Automation ZigBee Controller
```

Comment: I wouldn't change the channel from the receiver (or pi) unless you are using an ad-hoc network.  If you are using a Router, then the router is where you want to adjust the channel.  Clients talking to the router (such as the Pi) should adjust channel on connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can use the command iwlist channel to find the channel.

2) No idea, I suggest you look at iwconfig.

Comment: This answer didn't work for me. The `iwconfig` below did. Possibly things have changed since 2015

Answer (score 6):

`iwconfig` describes the state of the WiFi adaptor, and can modify it as well:

```
# iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"pichincha"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 00:25:9C:6B:1D:25   
          Bit Rate:54 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:****-****-****-****-****-****-****-****   Security mode:open
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=100/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

`iwfcofig` can also be used to set the channel, as in:

```
# iwconfig wlan0 channel 3
```

I haven't tried that, but that's what `man iwconfig` suggests.

Comment: Umm, only when wlan0 is associated with some other access point (e.g typical client situation).  On my (raspi 4b, 64-bit bullseye) system, at least, it does not show frequency when client is disassociated, or when I query a virtual interface that's running an access point.

'''
$ iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=31 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          
"""

Comment: `iwconfig` works only when wifi interface is 'managed', e.g, normal client, but not when it's the access point itself.  For that case, use `iw <ap> info`, which will show frequence, though not channel.  Found at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47398018/hostapd-how-to-know-the-frequency-of-ap-mode, 2nd answer.